# Playing Sound in Table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can anyone guide me on how to play sound .caf file in table view.Just like the Apple voice memo app.NCH Pocket Dictate App also implements this feature same way.I think it's pretty good from usability point of view and better use of UITableView.

My App stores user recorded voice.The list of recording is displayed as UITableView.I dont want users to go to special view where they can play voice and then have them return back to delete recording if they want.

Any slight hint will work too!

Thanks for looking at my problem.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer should do what you want.